# Cannot run the following code in Python terminal

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

From the following page (https://github.com/Babelscape/rebel/blob/main/setup.sh) I got the following code.

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup conda
source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

# create conda env
read -rp "Enter environment name: " env_name
read -rp "Enter python version (e.g. 3.7) " python_version
conda create -yn "$env_name" python="$python_version"
conda activate "$env_name"

# install torch
read -rp "Enter cuda version (e.g. 10.1 or none to avoid installing cuda support): " cuda_version
if [ "$cuda_version" == "none" ]; then
    conda install -y pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
else
    conda install -y pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=$cuda_version -c pytorch -c conda-forge
fi

# install python requirements
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Does anyone know what can be done to process this code effectively?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bash script. You only can run it in a Bash Shell.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I copy paste the above code in the Ubuntu shell, it says no such file or directory. I assume I have to cd to the folder in which it is installed?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-bash-script-in-linux/